# Django Multiple Users can view single model object

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

How to define a condition where we can set multiple users access for that single model object.

Let's suppose we have the following model.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.TextField()
```

And i have 2 users: `admin` and `jobert`

Since `user` field in above model is single one to one field which means either `admin` or `jobert` are saving that object.

if that object created by `admin` then jobert can't see that object and vice-versa for `jobert`.

How do i made that `user` field to accept or allow multiple users to access that object. i want `admin`and `jobert` users to access that model object.

Comment: By using a `ManyToManyField` instead.

Comment: How do I query or filter objects in views? `Project.objects.filter(user='admin')` , what is the  way for ManyToMany  Field Query?

Comment: just like with a `OneToOneField`: `Project.objects.filter(user__username='admin')`.

Comment: Thanks, how to filter only objects whose username contains both 'admin' and 'jobert' in  ManyToManyField ?

Comment: with `Project.objects.filter(user__username='admin').filter(user__username='jobert')`.

Comment: that works as per my question, what is the effective way or fastest way to filter the objects which is created by 'jobert' & objects which are shared between 'admin' and 'jobert'